# COUNT not returning expected values

Tags: mysql, count

Given the following relationship between my tables: [image]

I need to show the name of films which only have two starring actors like 'Seconday'.

```
SELECT act.cod_film,
(SELECT COUNT(act.cod_film) FROM film, act WHERE act.starring like 
'Seconday' and act.cod_film=film.cod_film) as namecounter
FROM act;
```

This always returns the films with the 'Seconday' actor, but the count is always same number. I need the number of 'Seconday' actors in each film.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can the films have any number of 'Seconday' actors? Your question says "two": but your query doesn't have that restriction.

Comment: yeah, only 2 secondary actors

Comment: Can you please post some of the actual output, and state what you would expect it to be?

Comment: of course, don't care about the language, if you have another question tell me.[sentence] (https://gyazo.com/89477115b1c1f3bc4f64880116786979)
[result] (https://gyazo.com/06aeea5f72b89759de420cc1fac57256)
[ORIGINAL SCHEMA] (https://gyazo.com/b4778b02b077e8c5d88617d27dfea1f4) 
Tables with cs_ prefix.
thank you!

Comment: of course, don't care about the language, if you have another question tell me.[sentence] (https://gyazo.com/89477115b1c1f3bc4f64880116786979)
[result] (https://gyazo.com/06aeea5f72b89759de420cc1fac57256)
[ORIGINAL SCHEMA] (https://gyazo.com/b4778b02b077e8c5d88617d27dfea1f4) 
Tables with cs_ prefix and only need to show title/name of all films that have only 2 secondary actors.
Secondary = 'Secundario'

thank you!

Comment: If I wrote a really nice but long solution query, took a screenshot of it, and added that image as an answer, would you be annoyed about the transcription and debugging effort? Please don't use images of data, just copy/paste some data into the question and format it using the `{}` icon seen in the toolbar. A little data (for each table) would make a huge difference. Then, also, show us the **expected result** (not an image preferred). Together **sample data** and **expected result**  is the best way to convey your needs.

Comment: I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

This will locate films with 2 'Secondary' actors

```
SELECT act.cod_film
FROM act
GROUP BY act.cod_film
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN act.starring like = 'Seconday' THEN 1 ELSE O END) = 2
```

which you can use in a subquery like this (or in many other possible ways)

```
SELECT *
FROM FILMS
WHERE cod_film IN (
                  SELECT act.cod_film
                  FROM act
                  GROUP BY act.cod_film
                  HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN act.starring like = 'Seconday' THEN 1 ELSE O END) = 2
                  )
```

or: Which you can use this way in a join

```
SELECT *
FROM FILMS
INNER JOIN (
           SELECT act.cod_film, COUNT(*) NUM_OF
           FROM act
           GROUP BY act.cod_film
           HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN act.starring like = 'Seconday' THEN 1 ELSE O END) = 2
           ) A ON FILMS.cod_film = A.cod_film
```

Notes:

1. `like` requires the use of a wildcard to be effective, don't substitute equals with like they are not the same things
2. you can adjust the `=` to `>=` as in `sum(case...) >= 2` if you wanted a minimum of 2 secondary actors

Comment: thanks, but i can't use group by or joins, only subquerys

Answer (score 0):

The act table is mentioned 2 times, try remove the act from the select count()

1. Preposition 1

> ```
> SELECT act.cod_film,
> (SELECT COUNT(act.cod_film) FROM film WHERE act.starring like 
> 'Seconday' and act.cod_film=film.cod_film) as namecounter
> FROM act;
> ```

2. Preposition 2

> ```
> SELECT act.cod_film, count(*)
> FROM act JOIN film ON (act.act.cod_film = film.cod_film)
> WHERE act.starring like 'Seconday'
> GROUP BY act.cod_film
> ```

Comment: thanks, but i can't use group by or joins, only subquerys